# Oracle SQL: Time difference in hours, mins and secs between two days and break/aggregate by date

Tags: oracle, date, aggregate, break

Here is a table with an employee work time for a task that may or may not straddle between two days (or more).

Need help to separately aggregate time in hours, minutes and seconds by date per employee and task id.

**Table example:**

```
Emp_ID | Task_ID | Task_start_date_time   | Task_stop_date_time  
 A1    | 123     | 01/13/2016 11:30:30 PM |  01/14/2016 12:30:30 AM  
 B1    | 124     | 01/16/2016 10:30:35 PM |  01/18/2016  2:30:35 AM  
 C1    | 125     | 01/19/2016  9:30:20 AM |  01/19/2016  2:30:20 PM  
 D1    | 126     | 01/20/2016  3:15:25 AM |  01/21/2016  2:25:25 PM
```

**Desired SQL result set:**

```
A1 | 123 | 01/13/2016 | 00:29:30  
A1 | 123 | 01/14/2016 | 04:30:30  
B1 | 124 | 01/16/2016 | 01:29:25  
B1 | 124 | 01/17/2016 | 24:00:00  
B1 | 124 | 01/18/2016 | 02:30:35  
C1 | 125 | 01/19/2016 | 05:00:00  
D1 | 126 | 01/20/2016 | 20:44:35  
D1 | 126 | 01/20/2016 | 14:25:25
```

Thanks in advance.

An addition: an eid and tid has more than one row? And need to aggregate the same way.

**Table example:**

```
Emp_ID | Task_ID | Task_start_date_time   | Task_stop_date_time  
 A1    | 123     | 01/13/2016 11:30:30 PM |  01/14/2016 12:30:30 AM  
 A1    | 123     | 01/14/2016 10:30:35 AM |  01/14/2016 2:30:35 PM  
 B1    | 124     | 01/16/2016 10:30:35 PM |  01/18/2016  2:30:35 AM  
 C1    | 125     | 01/19/2016  9:30:20 AM |  01/19/2016  2:30:20 PM  
 D1    | 126     | 01/20/2016  3:15:25 AM |  01/21/2016  2:25:25 PM
```

**Desired SQL result set:**

```
A1 | 123 | 01/13/2016 | 00:29:30  
A1 | 123 | 01/14/2016 | 08:30:30  
B1 | 124 | 01/16/2016 | 01:29:25  
B1 | 124 | 01/17/2016 | 24:00:00  
B1 | 124 | 01/18/2016 | 02:30:35  
C1 | 125 | 01/19/2016 | 05:00:00  
D1 | 126 | 01/20/2016 | 20:44:35
```

Comment: oops! the table and result layout did not come out correctly.

Comment: Also there is a typo in the "desired sql result set" part of my question. The second line should be:

A1 | 123 | 01/14/2016 | 00:30:30

Answer (score 0):

One of possibilities:

```
with data as (
  select emp_id eid, task_id tid, task_start_date_time d1, task_stop_date_time d2, 
         trunc(task_stop_date_time)-trunc(task_start_date_time)+1 cnt from tasks),
rec(eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, rn) as (
  select eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, 1 from data
  union all 
  select eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, rn+1 from rec where rn+1<=cnt),
res as (
  select eid, tid, rn, trunc(d1)+rn-1 dt, 
         least(d2, trunc(d1)+rn) - greatest(d1, trunc(d1)+rn-1) diff 
    from rec)
select eid, tid, dt, 
       to_char(trunc(diff*24), 'fm00')||':'||
       to_char(trunc(mod(diff*24*60, 60)), 'fm00')||':'||
       to_char(trunc(mod(diff*24*60*60, 60 )), 'fm00') diff
  from res order by eid, rn
```

Steps:

- 1 - subquery `data` - here I added column `cnt` containing number of days based on difference between start_date and end_date,
- 2 - recursive subquery `rec` - this generates desired number of rows for every row from input data,
- 3 - subquery `res` - added difference of proper values, this difference is in days,
- 4 - last query, converts `diff` from days to `hh:mm:ss` format.

Oracle 11g is needed for this query to run. I named table as `tasks`, below goes sample data and output.

```
create table tasks (Emp_ID varchar2(2), Task_ID number(6), Task_start_date_time date, Task_stop_date_time date);
insert into tasks values ('A1', 123, timestamp '2016-01-13 23:30:30', timestamp '2016-01-14 00:30:30');
insert into tasks values ('B1', 124, timestamp '2016-01-16 22:30:35', timestamp '2016-01-18 02:30:35');
insert into tasks values ('C1', 125, timestamp '2016-01-19 09:30:20', timestamp '2016-01-19 14:30:20');
insert into tasks values ('D1', 126, timestamp '2016-01-20 03:15:25', timestamp '2016-01-21 14:25:25');
```

Output:

```
EID        TID DT       DIFF      
--- ---------- -------- -----------
A1         123 16/01/13 00:29:29    
A1         123 16/01/14 00:30:30    
B1         124 16/01/16 01:29:25    
B1         124 16/01/17 24:00:00    
B1         124 16/01/18 02:30:34    
C1         125 16/01/19 05:00:00    
D1         126 16/01/20 20:44:35    
D1         126 16/01/21 14:25:25
```

---

**Update:** If you want to group values, as you mentioned in comments then you need to add group by clause for each day - see changes in subquery `res` and final select.

```
insert into tasks values ('A1', 123, 
                          timestamp '2016-01-14 10:30:35', 
                          timestamp '2016-01-14 14:30:35');

with data as (
  select emp_id eid, task_id tid, task_start_date_time d1, task_stop_date_time d2, 
         trunc(task_stop_date_time)-trunc(task_start_date_time)+1 cnt from tasks),
rec(eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, rn) as (
  select eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, 1 from data
  union all 
  select eid, tid, d1, d2, cnt, rn+1 from rec where rn+1<=cnt),
res as (
  select eid, tid, trunc(d1)+rn-1 dt, 
         sum(least(d2, trunc(d1)+rn) - greatest(d1, trunc(d1)+rn-1)) diff 
    from rec group by eid, tid, trunc(d1)+rn-1)
select eid, tid, dt, 
       to_char(trunc(diff*24), 'fm00')||':'||
       to_char(trunc(mod(diff*24*60, 60)), 'fm00')||':'||
       to_char(trunc(mod(diff*24*60*60, 60 )), 'fm00') diff
  from res order by eid, tid, dt
```

Output (change is in line 2: 30 minutes and 30 seconds from first row of your data and 4 hours from second row):

```
EID        TID DT          DIFF
--- ---------- ----------- -----------
A1         123 2016-01-13  00:29:29
A1         123 2016-01-14  04:30:30
B1         124 2016-01-16  01:29:25
B1         124 2016-01-17  24:00:00
B1         124 2016-01-18  02:30:34
C1         125 2016-01-19  05:00:00
D1         126 2016-01-20  20:44:35
D1         126 2016-01-21  14:25:25
```

Comment: Awesome, it works great! 

Ponder, thank you for the timely and accurate response !!!

Comment: An addition: an eid and tid has more than one row? And need to aggregate the same way. Example table entry: Emp_ID | Task_ID | Task_start_date_time   | Task_stop_date_time
 A1    | 123     | 01/13/2016 11:30:30 PM |  01/14/2016 12:30:30 AM ||
 A1    | 123     | 01/14/2016 10:30:35 AM |  01/14/2016  2:30:35 PM

Comment: @KumarSambhuni - Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35183195/edit) your original question an add this example. It's important. 
In the future please provide DDL and DML statements (similar to these I included in answer), it`s good starting point for people trying to help. Also please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies, didn't know the rules. New to posting questions on stack overflow. Will take enough care next time around.

Comment: No problem, your question remains open. I'm thinking if simple `group by` does not resolve it? But please add this example, maybe someone find beter  solution.

Comment: I've tried a simple group by clause but did not get the desired result set. Should I edit and remove my additional question in my original question and start a new thread with required DDL and DML? Please advise.

Comment: @KumarSambhuni - please see update at bottom part of my answer.

Comment: `connect by` and  other recursive  queries are slow against millions rows, be warned

Comment: This works for me like a charm. It's not running against huge data. Thanks again Ponder!